# How can we write cutom form and code for joomla login?

Tags: php, web, joomla, authentication, joomla-extensions

iam a beginner in Joomla. i don't want to customize or use modules like BTlogin or default login module in Joomla. i want to create fresh login module with minimum code, i dont know how the passwords are encrypted so please some one help me..

Comment: This question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to create a new module. Simply add your own template overrides, or even easier modify the default login module's template file(s). Leave the PHP codes intact and let Joomla handle the password hashing, authentication, registration etc.

Assuming your template did not override the default login module, its template file is /modules/mod_login/tmpl/default.php. Be careful not to remove form elements and PHP variables when you modify the file.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which Joomla version you are using.

But from Joomla 3.3, bcrypt algorithm used to create password hash.
Refer [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the php manual on this... It's a nice beginners guide:

[Safe Password Hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)